# How to make a toggling Mouseover button?

Tags: user-interface, wolfram-mathematica

I have to make a toggler-like control, which performs some action, when the mouse goes over it, and performs another action when it leaves the button, but does nothing while the mouse is over and moving.

To make it clear, it is not enough to simply find out whether the mouse is over a region or not, but **it must run some code *only* when the mouse enters and leaves the region.** (clarification requested by Szabolcs)

Sadly, the `AutoAction` option of `Button` behaves differently: it constantly tries to perform the action *while* the mouse is moving inside the object:

```
switch = False;
Button["Hover", switch = ! switch, AutoAction -> True]
Dynamic[switch]
```

On the other hand, a simple `Mouseover` command cannot perform code that is executed each time the mouse leaves the object:

```
in = out = 0;
Mouseover[
 Dynamic["out", (in++) &],
 Dynamic["in", (out++) &]
 ]
Dynamic[Column[{in, out}]]
```

I thought that the second argument of `Dynamic` could be used to define starting and ending actions for a `Mouseover` object, but had no success with this approach either.

```
start = end = False;
Dynamic[Mouseover["out", "in"], {(start = True) &, Null, (end = True) &}]
Dynamic[Column[{start, end}]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which framework are you using, put it in your question because there may be some already available implementation rather than writing one from scratch

Comment: @Noor Please see the tags: [tag:mathematica].  It's already mentioned.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to use this for?  Do you simply need to find out whether the mouse is over a region or not (doable), or you must run some code *only* when the mouse enters (or leaves) the region (I've no idea how to do that)

Comment: See edit, thanks for the wording.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
in = 0; out = 0;
Dynamic[Column[{in, out}]]
Module[{over = False},
 EventHandler[
  Pane[EventHandler[Dynamic[Framed[Pane[If[over, "In", "Out"], 40]]],
     {"MouseMoved" :> If[Not[over], over = True; in++]},
     PassEventsUp -> False], ImageMargins -> 4],
  {"MouseMoved" :> If[over, over = False; out++]}]]
```

What this does is to wrap the region for which you want to register the entries and exits into a slightly larger region using `Pane`. Both the inner region and the outer region have an `EvenHandler` which registers movements of the mouse. By setting `PassEventsUp->False` for the inner `EventHandler`, the `"MouseMoved"` events are passed to the outer `EventHandler` only if the mouse pointer is over the outer region but not over the inner region.

Comment: Elegant solution, I was thinking along the same lines. There seems to be a slight problem with very fast mouse movements not being registered, but I guess it happens to a simple Mouseover too.

Comment: Thanks. In my solution, I've chosen a margin of 4 pts around the inner region. Since the mouse position is sampled at a certain speed (about 20 times per second if I remember correctly) it might happen that you skip over this margin between two samplings if you move the mouse fast enough. Increasing `ImageMargins` in the code above should solve this.

Comment: I think there should be a thread specifically dealing with control elements that are not built into _Mathematica_ or perhaps only those that are not covered in the Documentation (e.g. the angular slider under Applications of [Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) is covered, but is not inbuilt).